# Complex query constraint on queryScope in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-query-builder

users table have the following columns:

1. created_at (timestamp)
2. last_order (timestamp)

when new users is created then last_order is null and created_at is current timestamp.
When user place an order then last order column is updated with timestamp of order placing time.
Now I want to retrieve all users who didn't place any order last 7 days. I define my user model as follows:

```
class User extends Model
{
    /**
     * @var string The database table used by the model.
     */
    public $table = 'users';

    /**
     * @var array Validation rules
     */
    public $rules = [
    ];
    public $hasMany  = [
        'voucher' => ['ItScholarBd\Api\Models\Voucher'],
        'order' => ['ItScholarBd\Api\Models\OrderLog']
    ];

   public function scopeCustomer($query)
    {
        return $query->where('role_id', '=', 5);
    }
   public function scopeNew($query,$days)
    {
        return $query->where('created_at', '>=', Carbon::now()->subDays($days));
    }
   public function scopeIdle($query,$days)
   {

       $dayOffset = Carbon::now()->subDays($days);

      return $query->where(function($q,$dayOffset){
        $q->whereNull('last_order')
          ->where('created_at','<',$dayOffset);
       })->orWhere(function($q,$days){
        $q->whereNotNull('last_order')
        ->whereRaw("DATEDIFF(created_at,last_order)>$days");
       });

   } 

}
```

Here `scopeNew()` is working perfectly but `scopeIdle()` is throwing the following error:

```
Type error: Too few arguments to function App\User::App\{closure}(),
  1 passed in .\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder.php on line 222 and exactly 2 expected
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't get to make up parameters for functions you don't control. The closure will be passed a single argument, and you need to import any other variables with `use`:

```php
public function scopeIdle($query, $days)
{
    $dayOffset = Carbon::now()->subDays($days);

    return $query
        ->where(function ($q) use ($dayOffset) {
            $q->whereNull('last_order')
                ->where('created_at', '<', $dayOffset);
        })
        ->orWhere(function ($q) use ($days) {
            $q->whereNotNull('last_order')
                ->whereRaw("DATEDIFF(created_at, last_order) > ?", [$days]);
       });
}
```

Note the use of parameters in the `whereRaw` statement, which can save you from SQL injection. You will also find your code easier to work on if you consistently indent and space it.

Comment: Thanks @milken32.  when last_order is null and created_at is older than $days then we get the data. But when created_at and last_order both are older than $days then no data is retrieved. Any idea?

Comment: You're not checking if they're both older than `$days`. You're checking if there's more than `$days` days difference between `created_at` and `last_order`. Since `last_order` is always greater than `created_at` you will always get a negative number as a result from `DATEDIFF()`.

Comment: See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff

Answer (score 0):

Try using a closure:

```
return $query->where(function($q) use ($dayOffset){
```